# Passing defrecord into function clojure

Tags: clojure, shortest-path

I'm currently working on a route planning robot in Clojure. The robot takes in a parcel which has a set of stops contained within it and then this robot is passed into a function which calculates the shortest route.

```
(defn journey [start end]
  (alg/pprint-path (alg/shortest-path all-edges {:start-node start, :end-node end, :cost-attr :weight})))


(defn fullpath [& stops]
  (doall (map (fn [a b] (journey a b)) stops (rest stops) )))
```

The two functions above calculate the shortest route between stops and print it out.

```
;;passed into robot
(defrecord Parcel [start
                   end
                   home])

;;passed into robotroute to plan journey of robot
(defrecord Robot [stops]) 

;;computes the path
(defn robotroute [robot]
  (def stops (:stops robot))
  (fullpath stops))


(def task1parcel (Parcel. :main-office :r131 :main-office))
(def task1robot (Robot. task1parcel))
(def task1 (robotroute task1robot))

(task1)
```

Above is my code for creating the robot and parcel. Robotroute is the function I am passing the robot into which is meant to strip out the stops and plan the route using fullpath.

All of the functions can be defined etc. However when trying to run task 1 I get the following error.

```
ClassCastException clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  funcprog2.core/eval13519 (form-init1291893531842170235.clj:1)
```

Can anyone assist with fixing this error?

Also moving forward I want a robot to hold multiple parcels so it can do more than one delivery in a row, what would be the best plan to move forward with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(defn fullpath [& stops]
  (doall (map (fn [a b] (journey a b)) stops (rest stops) )))`

function fullpath return a lazyseq . (task1)  will evaluate this lazeseq again Maybe you could just get your result by putting  "task1" in repl.

For example  `(def list '(1 2 3))` list is equal to `'(1 2 3).  (list)`  will end up getting "ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn"

Another point is that try

```
(defn robotroute [robot]
         (let [stops (:stops robot)] (fullpath stops)))
```

in clojure a suggestion is that  : use let rather than def to bind variable when defining a function because def means global

Comment: Please, you don't need to call it a "suggestion": *do not* use `def` within the body of a function. It creates a global var in the current namespace which is really not what was intended and it's generally a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

1. `(def stops`  inside roboroute - shouldn't that be a `let` ?
2. `(robotroute task1robot)` returns whatever `fullpath` returns, which is `(doall (map ...` - it's a sequence - and sequences are not callable/not a function (as the error suggests). Therefor invoking it like `(task1)` fails.